# Setting default tab in UITabBar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I'm almost finished with a project and am working out the last few UI kinks. My app uses a tab bar to navigate and for aesthetic purposes I want the app to open on the last tab (User Profile) instead of the first. I know I can reorder the tabs in Interface Builder but the tab bar would just look odd having the profile tab first and the home tab anywhere else. How can I leave the profile tab as the 5th tab yet by default open the app on that tab?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just set the selectedIndex of the tabBarController. Something along these lines.

```
var freshLaunch = true
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     if freshLaunch == true {
         freshLaunch = false
         self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 4 // 5th tab
     }
}
```

Comment: If you add this code in viewDidLoad() instead of viewWillAppear() then boolean variable is not needed.

Answer (score 32):

There is a nice way to do this straight from interface builder on your **tab bar controller** click the **identity inspector**, and set a **User Defined Runtime Attribute**.

In this case each index of the tab bar control is indexed like a 0 based array.  So the far left is 0, next to the right is 1, then 2 etc...

So in my case I wanted 'tasks' to be selected first, so you set the selectedIndex to type Number and value '1'.  Refer to my attached image.

[image]

Comment: doesn't work in the Xcode 8.02 version I have. Failed to set (selectedIndex) user defined inspected property on (UITabBarController): Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/A04810EB-0867-49C8-8967-78F1506FFADF/CarePointe.app> (loaded)' with name 'Wje-Ny-ZcC-view-IBi-mh-pkx'

Comment: hmm, really? I'm still doing this technique right now in my current project.  I'll check again though to see if there is still an issue.

Comment: If you can give more details about the error you are seeing, maybe post up your sample project I can take a look what might be causing it.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using `UISegue` from `UIStoryBoard`, you can use this in `UIViewController` where you're performing `UISegue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let tabBarController = segue.destination as? UITabBarController
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

or

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.selectedIndex = 1
   }

}
```

this code in your `UITabBarController` itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the First items view controller write

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2//required value
```

Comment: This only highlights the 3rd tab in the tab bar but doesn't switch to the associated view. (XCode 10.1)